# Paypal - authorize in popup redirects parent window instead of popup window

Tags: javascript, paypal

I have the web application. I want to implement next flow:

1. Merchants authorize in PayPal like it is described here
   https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/direct/identity/get-user-consent/
2. I get the authorization code and exchange it to access token.
3. Using access token I call Payments REST API and create payments on behalf of a merchant.

I tested this flow using Postman and it works fine.
Then I started to integrate this flow in my web app. 
For that when merchant clicks on the button "Connect Paypal" in my app, I want to open authorize dialog in a new window using window.open(). 
I expected that Paypal makes a redirect in the same popup window. But instead of this Paypal closes popup window and makes a redirect in a parent window.

I've tried to set childWindow.opener as null. In this case, Paypal closes popup window and doesn't do any redirects.

Example of code which I use for opening window:

```
var child = window.open('https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/signin/authorize?client_id=<client_id>&response_type=code&redirect_uri=<redirect_url_in_my_app>')
```

Do you have any idea how to make all redirects in child popup window instead of parent one?

Comment: Use iframe in popup, this is the one i can see as option without reloading the page.

Comment: It is not allowed by Paypal headers. I tried it

Answer (score 0):

Google developers developed a tool which makes it easy to handle window redirects , pop-ups and returning the data back .

Try using this https://github.com/google/web-activities